# Error as the connection string property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sql-server

Why am I getting this error:

> Connection state has not been intialized

when I'm using one method in other?

This is my `DbConnectio.cs`:

```
public class DbContext
{
        public SqlConnection sqlconn = null;

        public SqlConnection DbConnection 
        {
            get { return sqlconn; }
            set { value = sqlconn; }
        }

        public DbContext()
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTXDB"].ConnectionString;
            sqlconn = new SqlConnection(cs);
        }
}
```

`web.config`:

```
<add name="CTXDB" 
     connectionString="Data Source=Md;Initial Catalog=Md;User ID=sa;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is my Repo.cs - here I'm implementing my business logic:

```
DbContext db = new DbContext();

public Employee FindEmpById(int key)
{
        SqlConnection conn = db.DbConnection;

        try
        {
            var employee = new Employee();

            if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_GetEmployeeById", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", key);

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    employee.Emp_Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Emp_Id"]);
                    employee.EmpName = rdr["EmpName"].ToString();
                    employee.Email = rdr["Email"].ToString();
                    employee.Psw = rdr["Psw"].ToString();
                }
            }

            return employee;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Close();
                    conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
}
```

This `FindEmpById` I call in `DeleteEmpById` function

```
public void DeleteEmpById(int Key)
{
            SqlConnection Con = db.DbConnection;

            var x = FindEmpById(Key);

            if (x != null)
            {
                if (Con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    Con.Open();
                }

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_DeleteById", Con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", Key);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
}
```

Comment: why minus anything wrong

Comment: Can you edit the question and add / show us how you are declaring / getting the Connection String..?  also refactor you code and start to use the `using(){}` to wrap your sql objects, also show where in your code you are calling the `DeleteEmById, I would suggest that you create the connection string inside the .Config file and create a auto property that reads / sets the connection string. once the connection has been auto-disposed if you use the `using(){}` construct, then in the Delete method getting the connstring, and opening it, you won't need to check Con.State

Comment: Remove your try/catch/finally and replace it with a much cleaner `using`

Comment: @MethodMan could u plz reffer my code

Comment: your code need some very minor clean / up i have looked at your code and also is this EF that you are using ?

Comment: @MethodMan yes  im using Ef

Comment: then do not use the same connection, it will not hurt to create a new instance of the connection in side the Delete method.. read up on what Dispose means and does and I think you will understand why you are getting the error that you are getting..refer to the posted answer in regards to my earlier comments in learning / using the `using( ) { }` construct

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks a lot

Comment: `DbContext` seems to be his own class and has nothing to do with EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindEmpById` disposes the connection `conn.Dispose();`. So, when you try to use it afterwards, it is not valid any more.

Don't try to reuse a connection. Create a new connection each time you need one. Internally the physical connections are pooled automatically, i.e., the same physical connection will be reused when possible. Creating a new connection with `new SqlConnection` is lightweight.

Instead of doing

```
SqlConnection conn = db.DbConnection; // WRONG!
// All your try catch finally and testing for conn.State    --- WRONG!
```

do

```
// OK!
using (SqlConnection conn = db.CreateConnection()) {
    conn.Open();
    ...

} // Automatically closed and disposed here.
```

Where `CreateConnection` creates a new `SqlConnection` at each call. This is also much easier and straight forward. Change your `DbContext` class to

```
public class DbContext
{
    private static readonly string _connectionString;

    static DbContext()
    {
        _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTXDB"].ConnectionString;
    }

    public SqlConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

---

Your overhauled `FindEmpById` method becomes

```
public Employee FindEmpById(int key)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = db.CreateConnection())
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_GetEmployeeById", conn)) {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", key);

        var employee = new Employee();

        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            if (rdr.Read()) {
                employee.Emp_Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Emp_Id"]);
                employee.EmpName = rdr["EmpName"].ToString();
                employee.Email = rdr["Email"].ToString();
                employee.Psw = rdr["Psw"].ToString();
            }
        }
        return employee;
    }
}
```

Btw: You don't need to call `FindEmpById(Key)` before deleting. Just delete. It is not an error to delete 0 records in SQL.

```
public void DeleteEmpById(int Key)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = db.CreateConnection())
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_DeleteById", conn)) {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", Key);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```